# \multispan ->\omit error when using \pagebreak before multicolumn

Tags: tables, errors

I've seen that the `\multispan ->\omit` is a common error. But I couldn't figure it out. I'm getting

> ! Misplaced \omit. \multispan ->\omit
>
> \@multispan  l.12 \end{tabularx}

I tested with the following MWE to show the error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ltablex}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cc}
abc & abc \\
\pagebreak
\multicolumn{2}{c}{text}\\
abc & abc \\
abc & abc \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

What is the problem? Can someone explain?

Comment: you don't need ltablex/tabularx there (it can do nothing useful without an X column anyway) just use a standard `longtable` then `\pagebreak` will work.

Comment: I have a table that spans several pages, that's why. I strip that information for the sake of MWE-ness. But I wanted to show that the environment used was a `tabularx` in case that is the problem.

Comment: Longtable will do multipage tables (that is what ltablex is using anyway)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be that the `ltablex` package does not support that.  You are not using any `tabularx` features, so just use `longtable` here. This runs without error

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{cc}
abc & abc \\
\pagebreak
\multicolumn{2}{c}{text}\\
abc & abc \\
abc & abc \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

---

If you are committed to sticking with `ltablex` then you can do

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ltablex}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cc}
abc & abc \\
\noalign{\break}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{text}\\
abc & abc \\
abc & abc \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, I have a table typeset using `tabularx` and `ltablex` (for the `\pagebreak`). However, I removed that information to keep it simple. Is there a way to do it using `tabularx`?

Comment: @adn probably it's fixable but if someone takes two of my packages and breaks them in combination then they should fix it:-) I have a different merge of tabularx and longtable on ctan (ltxtable.sty) so you could use that instead, but in 99.9999% of the cases you don't need tabularx and it's better to just use longtable.

Comment: @adn see update, I added an ltablex version (against my better judgement:-)

Comment: Thanks, I will migrate to `longtable` per your advice. Thanks!